# Setting textbox's clickable background

Tags: html, asp.net, css, telerik

I need to set textbox background image that is clickable so i used div(position:absolute) tag above textbox in which i included image, but the problem is that image is located above text, i tried to set z-index of image to -1 but then image got behind textarea

```
#smiley {
        position:absolute;
       z-index:1;
    }

 <telerik:RadPane ID="Radpane5" runat="server" Height="100%" Scrolling="None" Width="100%">
                        <div id="smiley">
                            <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1013130_10200305067254687_188481208_n.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="40" width="40">
                        </div>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="chatBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Resize="Both" Rows="100" Width="100%"
                            EmptyMessage="type here" AutoPostBack="true" BorderStyle="None" Style="z-index:5; border: none; margin: 0 auto; outline: none">

                             </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to do after clicking the background image ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

`<input type="text" id="smiley" />
<input type="text" id="smiley1" />`

CSS

`#smiley:focus{background: red;}`
`#smiley1:focus{background: url("http://surrey-arg.org.uk/SARG/08000-TheAnimals/Images/Prey/Small_fish.jpg");}`

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/MPwmm/)